# How to get list of records using entity framework error -The model item passed into the dictionary , but this dictionary requires a model item

Tags: c#, entity-framework

how to get the list of records in the table using entity framework , im getting error -

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[SmartPondDataAccess.Alert]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SmartPondDataAccess.AlertsViewModel]'.

view model

```
   public class AlertsViewModel
    {
        public int Deviceid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> LowDO1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> LowDO2 { get; set; }

    }
```

c# code

```
public ActionResult Settings() {

            smartpondEntities entities = new smartpondEntities();
            return View(entities.Alerts);
        }
```

view

```
@model IEnumerable<SmartPondDataAccess.AlertsViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Settings";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_SmartPond.cshtml";
}


<table id="tblCustomers" class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:150px">Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Deviceid </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Did you try `return View(entities.Alerts.ToList());` instead of `return View(entities.Alerts);`?

Comment: yes tried. same eror

Comment: @SelimYıldız is right. And also, Alerts is not of type AlertsViewModel

Comment: how to typecast it to AlertsViewModel, and it should return list of AlertsViewModel.

Comment: I have added an answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Your page requires model which types of `IEnumerable<SmartPondDataAccess.AlertsViewModel>`.So you should convert `Alerts` to `AlertVewModel`:

```
public ActionResult Settings() {
    smartpondEntities entities = new smartpondEntities();
    var alertList = entities.Alerts.ToList();

    List<AlertsViewModel> alertViewModel = alertList.Select(s=> new AlertsViewModel()
                                                                {
                                                                    Deviceid = //....
                                                                }).ToList();
    return View(alertViewModel);
}
```